# Creating Login Screen with Phaser.io : http requests?

Tags: node.js, http, socket.io, phaser-framework

I would like to start with a disclaimer that I have no previous coding experience at all, and I have just learned HTML, CSS, JS, node.js, phaser.io, understanding all the jargon such as API, asynchronize, I/O driven, cookies & session, etc.. all that in the past 1.5 months on the web by myself, so if my question doesn't make sense please let me know.

I would ultimately like to make a cross-platform online multiplayer "webgame" (No realtime interaction between clients), I know it is ambitious but I don't mind take one step at a time, finishing the game in the period of 2-3 years on my spare time as a hobbyist, so let's move on to the actual question.

After doing all my research I decided to use phaser as client framework, PhoneGap to compile for crossplatform, and node.js + passport + mongodb for server, user authentication and storage. Since there are no realtime element between clients, and there are more tutorial on using express along with the stack of backend packages mentioned above. I am more  keen on using http protocol with express then using websocket or socket.io.

Now I have created a simple login screen with input field using phaser-input plugin, and a button to send the data out. I am surprised when I cannot find any Phaser API on http request.

**Q:Are there any Phaser API to do a http POST or GET request? if not is it possible to implement jQuery Ajax (does phaser include the jQuery library already or do I need to include the script as well?)? And if I should use socket.io anyway?**

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a phonegap project that use html as login screen too.
First. Yes and no, Phaser itself is just a framework. Phaser 's not a library. But if you want to make http request, i suggest create a Network.js that abstract all of your network call on different platform .I think you can use:

1. IOS: use Cordova http request.
2. Android: use Ajax is fine. Yes and it is possible to use jquery. Cordova, Phongap, IONic is nothing more than a web view. So you can use whatever js library you like.
3. Web: use Ajax too.